# Create bigrams with strings of length two as keys

Tags: python

How can one create a function `create_bigrams(l)` that takes in a list `l` of strings and returns a dictionary, `bigrams`, that have strings of length two as keys and `True` as values? The keys that are strings of length two should come from the list `l` of strings and is a letter combination from these strings.

For example:

`build_bigrams(['baka', 'kaka'])`should give the dictionary `{'ba': True, 'ak': True, 'ka': True}` thus ba, ak and ka are letter combinations from the string 'baka' and 'kaka'.

Comment: I dont know, what you indent to do with this dict further down the road, but if `True` is the only value you want to store, then maybe a `set` is more appropriate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
def build_bigrams(lst):
    return {s[i:i+2]: True for s in lst for i in range(len(s)-1)
}

>>> build_bigrams(['baka', 'kaka'])
{'ba': True, 'ak': True, 'ka': True}
```

Even more useful for a bigram model might be a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def build_bigrams(lst):
    return Counter(s[i:i+2] for s in lst for i in range(len(s)-1))
    
>>> build_bigrams(['baka', 'kaka'])
Counter({'ka': 3, 'ak': 2, 'ba': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the pair first then generate the dict

```py
def create_bigrams(l):
  def split_str(s):
    return [s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1)]
  return ({w:True for s in l for w in split_str(s)})

create_bigrams(['baka', 'kaka']) #{'ba': True, 'ak': True, 'ka': True}
```